# Matrix multiplication on both rows is badly aligned

Tags: vertical-alignment, matrices

I try to make matrix multiplication like

```
\begin{align*}
~ & \begin{bmatrix}
m_{0} & m_{1} & m_{2} & m_{3} \\
m_{4} & m_{5} & m_{6} & m_{7} \\
m_{8} & m_{9} & m_{10} & m_{11} \\
m_{12} & m_{13} & m_{14} & m_{15}
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{0} & v_{1} & v_{2} & v_{3}
\end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix}
r_{0} & r_{1} & r_{2} & r_{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
```

But vector r is not correctly align (vertically) with matrix m.
Moreover, I don't want specifics packages (I use Latext inside MathJax).

Do you have some tips for me ?

Thanks

**EDIT**
I add another way with same issue:

```
\[
\begin{array}{cc}
~ & \begin{bmatrix}
m_{0} & m_{1} & m_{2} & m_{3} \\
m_{4} & m_{5} & m_{6} & m_{7} \\
m_{8} & m_{9} & m_{10} & m_{11} \\
m_{12} & m_{13} & m_{14} & m_{15}
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{0} & v_{1} & v_{2} & v_{3}
\end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix}
r_{0} & r_{1} & r_{2} & r_{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{array}
\]
```

I want this kind of design
[image]

Comment: please provide complete but small document with your matrix. what is `\X`? welcome to tex.se!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big bracket has different side bearings than the smaller one.

Add some visually determined spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
& \begin{bmatrix}
  m_{0} & m_{1} & m_{2} & m_{3} \\
  m_{4} & m_{5} & m_{6} & m_{7} \\
  m_{8} & m_{9} & m_{10} & m_{11} \\
  m_{12} & m_{13} & m_{14} & m_{15}
  \end{bmatrix}
\\
  \begin{bmatrix}
  v_{0} & v_{1} & v_{2} & v_{3}
  \end{bmatrix}
& \mspace{5mu}
  \bigl[\begin{matrix}
  \makebox[\widthof{$m_{12}$}]{$r_{0}$} &
  \makebox[\widthof{$m_{13}$}]{$r_{1}$} &
  \makebox[\widthof{$m_{14}$}]{$r_{2}$} &
  \makebox[\widthof{$m_{15}$}]{$r_{3}$}
  \end{matrix}
  \mspace{5mu}
  \bigr]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I valid solution BUT I can't use calc package on MathJax. I think now I must find a way to improve my Latex/MathJax. Thanks !

Comment: @Rominitch MathJax has nothing to do with this site.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is nothing here to align, why do you use `align*`? two `\[` and `\]` are enough. Also, this is a vector-matrix multiplication, the inner dimensions must match and the result taking outer dimensions, so v[1-by-4] x M[4-by-4] = r[1-by-4]. I re-ordered the multiplication accordingly and removed `align*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}   

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{0} & v_{1} & v_{2} & v_{3}
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
m_{0} & m_{1} & m_{2} & m_{3} \\
m_{4} & m_{5} & m_{6} & m_{7} \\
m_{8} & m_{9} & m_{10} & m_{11} \\
m_{12} & m_{13} & m_{14} & m_{15}
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
r_{0} & r_{1} & r_{2} & r_{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't search to write on one row but two

Comment: @Rominitch - Please post an image of the desired alignment, your question is not clear; you say _But vector r is not correctly align (vertically) with matrix m_, `r` and `m` are on two different lines, in this case you can only **horizontally**  align them.